# Validation not success in struts2 application

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-validation

I am simply trying form validation using Struts2 annotation like below code,

Home.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="LoginClass" method="post">

<s:textfield name="Uname" label="User Name" />

<s:textfield name="Pwd" label="Password" />

<s:submit Value="Login" />

</s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

LoginCheckingClass.java :

```
package com.struts2;    

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Results;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.annotations.*;

@Results({
       @Result(name="success", location="/LoginSuccessPage.jsp"),
       @Result(name="input", location="/Home.jsp")

    })

public class LoginCheckingClass extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String Uname;
    public String Pwd;


    @Action(value="/LoginClass")
    public String execute() {

         return SUCCESS;                
    }

    @RequiredFieldValidator(message="Name should not blank.")
    public String getUname()
    {
        return Uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname)
    {
        this.Uname = uname;

    }

    @RequiredFieldValidator(message="Password should not blank.")
    public String getPwd()
    {
        return Pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String Pwd)
    {
        this.Pwd = Pwd;

    }

}
```

Web.xml :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 version="2.5">
  <display-name>Struts2Application</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
  <filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

But Page always redirecting to LoginSuccessPage.jsp even there is empty fields.

i think i am doing annotation misplace so someone tell me where i am wrong?

Note : I am doing this app by looking http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_annotations.htm

Comment: Use `@RequiredStringValidator` for String-s.

Comment: @AleksandrM Its working but validation error not display after redirect to Home.jsp.I am doing this one by looking  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_annotations.htm

Answer (score 0):

The annotations are put on setter methods. Imagine the value you want to assign to the field that has a wrong value. The setter is invoked but it should be validated for a correct value.

```
@RequiredFieldValidator(message="Name should not blank.")
@RequiredStringValidator(message = "Name should not blank.")    
public void setUname(String uname)
{
    this.Uname = uname;
}

@RequiredFieldValidator(message="Password should not blank.")
@RequiredStringValidator(message = "Password should not blank.")    
public void setPwd(String Pwd)
{
    this.Pwd = Pwd;
}
```

Comment: if i am doing mistake in "The annotations are put on setter methods" then see this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_annotations.htm

Comment: @M.Manivasagam I'd say what works is more important than what a tutorial says; did you try on the setters? Even in the outdated S2 docs (I have a TODO to fix this) [here](https://struts.apache.org/docs/validation-annotation.html) they're on the setters. Did you consider reading the S2 docs?

Comment: I understand you @Roman C  I tried in setters also but same issue...Really i am confused with S2 validation.

Comment: @M.Manivasagam Include complete details like S2 version. You can also create a git repo, put your project's source, config, Maven pom, etc there and perhaps someone can look at it.